# How can I make jest-mongodb work with NODE_ENV?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, global-variables, ts-jest

I am trying to use `jest-mongodb` with `ts-jest` and it works fine on my local machine, but when I started to run it in docker or somewhere isolated like CircleCI, it refuses to work and keeps saying:

```
Error: Jest: Got error running globalSetup - /app/node_modules/@shelf/****-mongodb/setup.js, reason: Instance Exited before being ready and without throwing an error!
```

As I understand that's the problem that these jest libraries do not work in an ordinary way with process.env.

Or if I directly feed the uri like this:

```
  connection = await MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:53251,127.0.0.1:53252,127.0.0.1:53253/?replicaSet=testset', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  });
```

It throws:

[image]

My current setup is:

jest.config.js

```
const { defaults: tsjPreset } = require('ts-jest/presets')

/** @type {import('ts-jest/dist/types').InitialOptionsTsJest} */
module.exports = {
    preset: '@shelf/jest-mongodb',
    transform: tsjPreset.transform,
}
```

jest-mongodb.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    mongodbMemoryServerOptions: {
        binary: {
            version: '4.0.3',
            skipMD5: true,
        },
        instance: {},
        autoStart: false,
        replSet: {
            count: 3,
            storageEngine: 'wiredTiger',
        },
    },
};
```

globalConfig.js

```
{"mongoUri":"mongodb://127.0.0.1:54576,127.0.0.1:54577,127.0.0.1:54578/?replicaSet=testset"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just bumped into the same issue. I upgraded `mongodb-memory-server` from `7.4.1` to `8.4.2` and that solved the problem. I hope this would help!